# read.csv doesn't load data properly

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

I am trying to replicate R syntax (https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/book-en/introduction-to-gams.html) that starts like this:

```
isit <- read.csv("data/ISIT.csv")
head(isit)
```

```
> SampleDepth Sources Station Time Latitude Longitude     Xkm    Ykm Month Year
> 1         517   28.73       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> 2         582   27.90       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> 3         547   23.44       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> 4         614   18.33       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> 5        1068   12.38       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> 6        1005   11.23       1    3  50.1508  -14.4792 -34.106 16.779     4 2001
> BottomDepth Season Discovery RelativeDepth
> 1        3939      1       252          3422
> 2        3939      1       252          3357
> 3        3939      1       252          3392
> 4        3939      1       252          3325
> 5        3939      1       252          2871
> 6        3939      1       252          2934
```

Pretty basic, and until today I've had no problems

However, today when I type this (I used a slightly different file path):

```
isit <- read.csv("ISIT.csv")
head(visit)
```

I instead get this:

```
> SampleDepth..Sources...Station...Time...Latitude...Longitude...Xkm...Ykm...Month...Year...BottomDepth...Season...Discovery...RelativeDepth.
> 1                                                                      517,28.73,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,3422
> 2                                                                       582,27.9,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,3357
> 3                                                                      547,23.44,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,3392
> 4                                                                      614,18.33,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,3325
> 5                                                                     1068,12.38,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,2871
> 6                                                                     1005,11.23,1,3,50.1508,-14.4792,-34.106,16.779,4,2001,3939,"1",252,2934
>
```

Am I missing something really basic?

I tried converting this to excel (using text to columns), updating R to 4.3.2, and re-installing the packages, I got the same result

Comment: Hi Conrad Baldner, welcome to SO. Your packages won't cause this behaviour as `read.csv()` is a base R function. I ran your code on the original [ISIT.csv](https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/pres-en/data/ISIT.csv) and could not reproduce your issue. Therefore, it is likely something has changed in your copy of ISIT.csv. Try downloading the file from the source to see if that helps.

Comment: `read.csv('https://r.qcbs.ca/workshop08/pres-en/data/ISIT.csv')` works fine for me.

Comment: Thanks! I re-downloaded the file and it worked